Rayleigh Quotient Iteration and norms with significance
For $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n*n}$ and $A=A^{T}$, Rayleigh Quotient Iteration is defined by :
select $v^{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $||v_{0}||_{2}=1$. For $k=1,2,\ldots$
1)Compute
$\lambda^{k-1}=[\vec{v}^{k-1}]^{T}A\vec{v}^{k-1}$, and  solve $(A-\lambda^{k-1}\mathbf{I_{n})}\vec{w}=\vec{v}^{k-1}$ for $\vec{w}$.
2)Compute $v^{k}=\frac{\vec{w}}{||\vec{w}||_{2}}$
Assume A=
\begin{bmatrix}
d_{1} & 0  \\
0 & d_{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
with $d_{1}>d_{2}$ and $\vec{v}^{k-1}=[v_{1}^{k-1},v_{2}^{k-1}]^{T}$ with $v_{1}^{k-1}\neq 0$ and $v_{2}^{k-1}\neq 0$
a)Express components of $\vec{v}^{k}=[v_{1}^{k},v_{2}^{k}]^{T}$ in terms of $v_{1}^{k-1}$ and $v_{2}^{k-1}$
b)Assume,in addition that $v_{1}^{k-1}\approx 1$ and $v_{2}^{k-1}\approx 0$. Show that $||\vec{v}^{k}-\vec e_{1}||_{2}\approx ||\vec v^{k-1}-\vec e_{1}||_{2}^{3}$ where $e_{1}=[1,0]^{T}$ What is the significance of the result? Solve those by using $\sqrt{1+x}\approx{1+\frac{x}{2}}$ for $x\approx 0$
My attempt is:
$v^{k-1}=
\begin{bmatrix} 
 (v_{1}^{k-1})^{T}&\\  
 (v_{2}^{k-1})^{T}&\\  
\end{bmatrix}$
Then $[\vec{v}^{k-1}]^{T}A\vec{v}^{k-1}=[v_{1}^{(k-1)},v_{2}^{(k-1)}] \begin{bmatrix}
d_{1} & 0  \\
0 & d_{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
 (v_{1}^{k-1})^{T}&\\  
 (v_{2}^{k-1})^{T}&\\  
\end{bmatrix}$, which is same as $||v_{1}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{1}+||v_{2}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{2}=\lambda^{k-1}$. Moreover $(A-\lambda^{k-1}\mathbf{I})=\begin{bmatrix}
d_{1}-||v_{1}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{1}-||v_{2}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{2} & 0  \\
0 & d_{2}-||v_{1}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{1}-||v_{2}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}$ Hence $(A-\lambda^{k-1}\mathbf{I})^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{d_{1}-||v_{1}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{1}-||v_{2}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{2}} & 0  \\
0 & \frac{1}{d_{2}-||v_{1}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{1}-||v_{2}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{2}}  \\
\end{bmatrix}$. Using $||v^{k}||_{2}=1$ for all k, $d_{1}-||v_{1}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{1}-||v_{2}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}d_{2}=d_{1}-d_{1}[||v_{1}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}+||v_{2}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}]+d_{1}||v_{2}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}-d_{2}||v_{2}^{(k-1)}||_{2}^{2}=(d_{1}-d_{2})||v_{2}^{k-1}||_{2}^{2}$.
, $d_{2}-||v_{1}^{k-1}||_{2}^{2}d_{1}-||v_{2}^{k-1}||_{2}^{2}d_{2}=(d_{2}-d_{1})||v_{1}^{k-1}||_{2}^{2}$. Hence $(A-\lambda^{k-1}\mathbf{I})^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{(d_{1}-d_{2})||v_{2}^{k-1}||_{2}^{2}} & 0  \\
0 & \frac{1}{(d_{2}-d_{1})||v_{1}^{k-1}||_{2}^{2}}  \\
\end{bmatrix}$ implies that $w=(A-\lambda^{k-1}\mathbf{I})^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} 
 (v_{1}^{k-1})^{T}&\\  
 (v_{2}^{k-1})^{T}&\\  
\end{bmatrix}$ is \begin{bmatrix} 
 \frac{(v_{1}^{k-1})^{T}}{(d_{1}-d_{2})||v_{2}^{k-1}||_{2}^{2}}&\\  
 \frac{(v_{2}^{k-1})^{T}}{(d_{2}-d_{1})||v_{1}^{k-1}||_{2}^{2}}&\\  
\end{bmatrix}
Also when I write $v_{2}^{k-1}\approx \epsilon$, I find that $v_{1}^{k-1}\approx \sqrt(1-\epsilon^{2})$ and calculated $||\vec v^{k-1}-\vec e_{1}||_{2}^{3}$ as $\epsilon^{3}$
However after here I could not continue step by step in logical way for the other term which is $||\vec{v}^{k}-\vec e_{1}||_{2}$ .Also the problem of finding the norm of $||w||$ becomes complicated for me. Therefore I need help. Also I do not know well what the significance of the result means mathematically in the last step.
Thank you in advance
